# Displaying the latest topics with the first post from the forum to the website

Tags: sql, modx

There is a code that displays the latest topics from the xenforo forum on the modx site, but you still need to display the message of the first post.

```
$sql = 'SELECT thread_id,title,node_id,last_post_date,user_id,last_post_username
FROM `xf_thread`
WHERE node_id NOT IN (0)
ORDER BY `last_post_date` DESC
LIMIT '.$count.';';
```

I understand that you need to add a message selection and post ID.

```
SELECT post_id,message
FROM `xf_post`
INNER JOIN xf_thread ON xf_thread.thread_id = xf_post.thread_id
WHERE xf_thread.first_post_id = xf_post.post_id
```

But I don't understand how to do this correctly.

When adding this line

```
INNER JOIN xf_thread ON xf_thread.thread_id = xf_post.thread_id
```

Everything breaks.

Please help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What to do with mysqli problems? Errors like mysqli\_fetch\_array(): Argument #1 must be of type mysqli\_result and such](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22662488/what-to-do-with-mysqli-problems-errors-like-mysqli-fetch-array-argument-1-m)

Comment: Your question is really about SQL in the context of ModX.  It would help to strip out all of the other irrelevant code and to specify exactly what you mean by "Everything breaks" - what error message do you get, have you confirmed that those tables and fields exist etc.?

Comment: You are absolutely right, the problem was that I did not know how to correctly compose the request and syntax.
This is how I got it to work :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
`xf_thread`.thread_id,
`xf_thread`.title,
`xf_thread`.node_id,
`xf_thread`.post_date,
`xf_thread`.user_id,
`xf_thread`.username,
`xf_thread`.first_post_id,
`xf_post`.post_id,
`xf_post`.message
 FROM `xf_thread`
INNER JOIN `xf_post` ON (`xf_post`.`thread_id` = `xf_thread`.`thread_id`)
 WHERE (`xf_post`.`post_id` = `xf_thread`.`first_post_id`) 
 AND node_id NOT IN (0)
ORDER BY post_date DESC
LIMIT '.$count.';
```

Comment: If this is your own answer (as I suspect that it is), then you need to say so, *in the answer* (and also add some explanation, if possible). Don't rely on comments (on your question) to 'point to' the answer.